# Strange performance quirk in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, performance, sorting

I experience a strange differences in performance of simple task depending of array I am working with. The task is to calculate sum of those elements in array which are greater than 5. Task is performed on arrays with equal lenghts.

I try the very same approach on three different array objects:

1) var hugeArray1 - array with all elemenets randomly picked from 0:10 range

2) var hugeArray2 - copy of hugeArray1 sorted with Array.prototype.sort()

3) var hugeArray3 - handcrafted but sorted array with values from 0:10 range, spread to equaly cover this interval.

I try to calculate sum of elements greater than 5 many times for each Array and then average them. What is strange, time needed varies a lot for those three arrays.

1) hugeArray1: 5.805ms

2) hugeArray2: 15.738ms

3) hugeArray3: 3.753ms

Result for array sorted with sort() is extreamly poor. Why is that? it looks like sort() returns some kind of wraper/proxy instead of 'native' Array, which affects performance. I tried it on 2 computers. Also i tried to change order of testing.

I include code below, please tell me what is happening here.

```
// random array with elements 0-10 of size n    
function randomArray(n) {
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        arr.push(Math.random() * 10);
    }
    return arr;
};

// measures time of execution
function measureTime(f) {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    f();
    var stop = new Date().getTime();
    return stop - start;

};

// enumerate ofer array and calculate sum of elementsgreater than 5
function sumGreaterThan5(arr) {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        if (arr[i] > 5.0)
            sum += arr[i];
    }
    return sum;
}

// generate array os size 'size' with elements with constant step to fill interval 0:10
function generateSortedArr(size) {
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        arr.push(i * 10 / size);
    }
    return arr;
}

var huge = 1000000;
var hugeArray1 = randomArray(huge);
var hugeArray2 = hugeArray1.slice(0).sort();
var hugeArray3 = generateSortedArr(huge);

var hugeArrays = [hugeArray1, hugeArray2, hugeArray3];

hugeArrays.forEach(x=> {
    var res = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
        res.push(measureTime(function () {
            sumGreaterThan5(x);
        }));
    }
    console.log(res.reduce((prev, curr)=> prev + curr) / res.length);
});
```

```js
// random array with elements 0-10 of size n    
function randomArray(n) {
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        arr.push(Math.random() * 10);
    }
    return arr;
};

// measures time of execution
function measureTime(f) {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    f();
    var stop = new Date().getTime();
    return stop - start;

};

// enumerate ofer array and calculate sum of elementsgreater than 5
function sumGreaterThan5(arr) {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        if (arr[i] > 5.0)
            sum += arr[i];
    }
    return sum;
}

// generate array os size 'size' with elements with constant step to fill interval 0:10
function generateSortedArr(size) {
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        arr.push(i * 10 / size);
    }
    return arr;
}

var huge = 1000000;
var hugeArray1 = randomArray(huge);
var hugeArray2 = hugeArray1.slice(0).sort();
var hugeArray3 = generateSortedArr(huge);

var hugeArrays = [hugeArray1, hugeArray2, hugeArray3];


hugeArrays.forEach(function(x){
    var res = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
        res.push(measureTime(function () {
            sumGreaterThan5(x);
        }));
    }
    console.log(res.reduce(function(prev, curr){return prev + curr},0) / res.length);
});
```

Comment: Does time include time for sorting?

Comment: No, look at the code included.

Comment: Running it in browser, I get expected behavior (`5.892, 1.53, 1.84`).  Are you sure?

Comment: I got ( `4.109, 0.856, 0.857` )

Comment: please us `jspref` to test performance and put a link here with the results.

Comment: @vsync jsperf that is dead for the last year?

Comment: @zerkms - wow really? what happened??

Comment: using this snipped above (I dont know how it was embeded here, it wasn't here when i created this post) i get (5.658 1.975 1.992). When I run this on my Node.js on the same machine, (from cli) I get (5.808 15.508 3.687). Are there any optimization flags I should launch my Node.js with?